# Add an activity indicator to tab bar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, uistoryboard

I am using story boards and came accross this problem. I need to add an activity indicator to a tab bar which has a table view and map view. So basically till it finds the current location i want the activity indicator to run. I did this using storyboards by adding a viewcontroller before the tabbed bar but nothing happens after it finishes. So i'd like to know how you add an activity indicator to a tabbed bar application and once activity finishes to load the tabbed bar.

Answer (score 3):

you can add the activity indicator view to a tabbar like this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator release];
```

self.tabBarController is a UITabBarController. this will show a gray activity indicator at (0,0) in the tab bar view. You can change the frame of the activity indicator to set the location where you want it to appear on the tabbar.

Comment: where do you write this code? appdelegate? I have a class called currentlocationfinder which finds the current location. but that doesnt have a view.

Comment: you can add it in the app delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method like this: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator release];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

Comment: Hi Sorin.. i have used above code to add activity indicator.. but as i have more than one tabbarcontroller. when i addsubview like this

Comment: activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(80, 2, 20, 20);
  
  
GroceryApplicationAppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  
[app.tabBarControllerSomeday.tabBar addSubview:activityIndicator];
[app.tabBarControllerGrocery.tabBar addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator release];

its getting added only in last tabbar (tabBarControllerGrocery).

Answer (score 0):

you can use customtabbar  for the same as in the following link and you can add  activity indicator as a sub view to any tab -button  you needed

[custom tab bar controller](http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/)

hope this help
 regards